# AngularJs ng-if how i can use it with my scenario

Tags: angularjs

This is my current code where i am displaying sub menus and it works fine.

I need slightly changed behaviour i.e. show sub menus text based on condition. e.g. show **Menu 1** OR **MENU ONE** based on condition value which i am getting back from my controller. The same logi

All i need to know **How can i use `ng-if` statement here?**

```
<li><a class="pointer" ng-show="IsTrue" data-ng-click="sum()">Menu 1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is change

```
<li><a class="pointer" ng-show="IsTrue" data-ng-click="sum()">Menu 1</a></li>
```

into

```
<li><a class="pointer" ng-show="IsTrue" data-ng-click="sum()">{{ menu }}</a></li>
```

and in the controller write the logic

```
$scope.menu = condition ? "Menu 1" : "Menu One";
```

Comment: You answers seems quite good. but i will wait for some other better way before marking it Answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is an option :

```
<a class="pointer" ng-show="IsTrue" ng-click="selectedMenu='menu1'; sum()">click to vuew
<div ng-if="selectedMenu == 'menu1'"> MENU </div></a>
```

you can use ng-show too...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) directive as it allows for an expression. Example:

```
<button ng-init="IsTrue = false" ng-click="IsTrue = !IsTrue">Change</button>
<ul>
  <li><a ng-bind="IsTrue ? 'Menu 1' : 'MENU ONE'"></a></li>
</ul>
```

***edit***

Example updated.

Comment: im getting some error e.g. missing attribute. would be nice if you give example using ng-bind specific to my code above. thanks